# Set focus after jAlert

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery plugin **jAlert** to show alert box.

I want to focus a textbox after showing jAlert, like this:

```
jAlert("Error", "Please enter EmailID.", function(){
  document.getElementById('txtEmail').focus();
}, 1);
```

But this code doesn't wait for user to click OK button and textbox gets focus before clicking OK button.

So how to focus it after user clicks, like a callback function.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use  $("#txtEmail").focus();

Comment: Thanks @satishrajak, its working. Can you please put it as answer and pls try to explain why it works and the basic JS doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jAlert doesn't operate like JavaScript alert and jAlert has a callback function  and take refrence from [enter link description here](http://flwebsites.biz/jAlert/)

```
 $("#txtEmail").focus();
```

Comment: Below code is not working, what is wrong

$.jAlert({
                'title': title,
                'content': error,
                'theme': "red",
                'backgroundColor': 'white',
                'autofocus': inputitem,
                'btns': [
                    { 'text': 'OK', 'theme': 'red' }
                ], function() {
                    $("#" + inputitem).focus();
                }
            });